# Draw a grid or use an image on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, opengl-es

I want to create a simple Sudoku grid. Something like this:
http://i1-mac.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/31-3-33_1.png

Is it a good idea to create an image of the grid and use as background image and then lay out my numbers on this or should I draw the grid using OpenGL or something?

If using image, what size is appropriate?

If OpenGL, how is that done?

Best Regards
Linus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple. No need for OpenGL. A background image will work perfectly well for a suduku grid unless you want crazy animations.

You also left out CoreGraphics as an option... which would fit somewhere in between background image and opengl in terms of flexibility and ease of use.... still... background image is so easy I don't know why you wouldn't just use that.

For sizes, keep in mind you need to support iPad (1024 x 768), iPhone 4 Retina Display (640 x 960) and iPhone (320 x 480)... also if you show the status bar, or other ui elements, you'll need to account for that. The sizes of those elements are documented and widely available.

Answer (score 1):

I would throw in another possible solution: use CoreAnimation. In the case of the sudoku grid you could just use one `CATextLayer` for each number. You could then use the layer's `borderWidth` property to get the border of the layer for the grid.

Another possible solution is to have a root layer which draws the grid, either by setting an image to the `content` property of the layer or by drawing the grid yourself using CoreGraphics in the `drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx` method. Then add your numbers as `CATextLayers`. The cool thing is that you can now easily fade in or fade out the numbers. You could also change the background of each individual field by setting the `CATextLayer`'s `backgroundColor` property.

As always: TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: Thanks @GorillaPatch. For now I just created a .png image with the grid. Now I'm trying to put the numbers in the correct places. I have all my numbers in a NSMutableArray. I loop through this but I can't reuse the same CATextLayer as it gets overwritten. I was trying to do it like this: http://snipt.net/Linuus/nothing?key=3e47b75000b0924b6c9ba5759a7cf15d  I don't calculate the placing of the numbers here but it was just a test. Only the last character gets printed as it is overwritten each time...

Comment: The answer is simple: you simply do not recycle the CATextLayers. You have to create a new text layer for each number. These layer objects are very lightweight so it should not affect your performance if you draw 81 layers. However in iOS UIViews are also a relatively _thin_ wrapper around CALayers. So if you feel more comfortable with UITextFields, then just try them and profile your app with the CoreAnimation instrument to check out the frame rate. If you need to optimize you can always go one next step more low-level.

Answer (score 0):

An image (set in an image view) would probably be the simplest solution, but a better choice is to create a UIView subclass and handle the drawing yourself by overriding `drawRect:` (if nothing else you don't have to deal with the memory overhead of loading the background image). OpenGL would be overkill, but Quartz 2D drawing (part of CoreGraphics) is easy enough and would work well here. Take a look at CGContextMoveToPoint(), CGContextAddLineToPoint(), CGContextStrokePath() and related methods. You'll have to do some work to layout the grid properly (especially if you want to support multiple devices / orientations) but the drawing itself shouldn't take much code.